# What's the difference between "dofile" in lua and "luaL_dofile" in the C API?

Tags: c, lua, lua-api

Using the Lua 5.3.4 C API, this works:

```
luaL_dostring(lua, "dofile('mnemonics.lua')");
```

But this fails to execute the file:

```
luaL_dofile(lua, "mnemonics.lua");
```

Instead, it reports "attempt to call a string value".

When I replace it with

```
luaL_loadfile(lua, "mnemonics.lua");
```

it returns `LUA_OK`, but it doesn't push a function on the stack like it's supposed to. In fact, the stack is empty (`gettop` reports 0) afterwards.

I can use the dostring workaround, but either I'm missing something, or there's a bug.

Comment: This is really weird. A wild guess: something that happened earlier in your C code corrupted your `lua` state? Try running the program with Valgrind.

Comment: Can you show us a minimal example that reproduces the problem you're seeing because I can't.

Comment: In searching for a minimal example I found that the problem was caused by trying to pop an empty stack. I had misunderstood the behavior of a call to `lua_settable`.

I believe the reason the Lua command worked when the C API command didn't is that the stack gets cleaned up at the transition between C code and Lua code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popping from an empty stack will cause unexpected behavior. The Lua interpreter cleans up the stack between executing C code and executing Lua code, so the messed up stack didn't affect the `dofile` in Lua.